# How to check if WiFi authentication failed

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I enable WiFi on my app. The password for a network is already store on the device and the device should connect automatically to WiFi without any user interaction. However, there is a chance that the network password has changed. I would like to prompt the user "Hey your WiFi failed to connect". Ideally I would want to know that the password is wrong or any other authentication failure that can be inferred as password is wrong.

How do I do this? It seems I only have access to "connected".

What I tried:

```
SupplicantState supState;
wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
supState = wifiInfo.getSupplicatState();
```

Sadly that only tells me `COMPLETED` - all authentication completed. **I want to know when authentication FAILS**.

*More info*: I don't know the password nor care what it is. I simply need to say to the user that they are failing to connect to WiFi and display it to the user.

Comment: they just don't want us to mess with their business. AOSP doesn't want non-os apps handling UI events related to what they deem low level, such as wpa_supplicant stuff. They will keep hiding and hiding stuff until you can no longer do anything unless you are root or  a system app

Answer (score -1):

```
   val errorCode = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_ERROR, -1)
```

if failed the errorCode will be not -1